# Select defined ranges of rows in column and transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I need select in loop defined range of rows in one particular column and then each this block transposed into row.

I have data in column A:

```
row    A
1      City_1
2      Street_1
3      StreetNo_1
4      State_1
5      City_2
6      Street_2
7      StreetNo_2
8      State_2
9      City_3
10     Street_3
11     StreetNo_3
12     State_3
```

and so forth... And I need to pick up every e.g. "quaternion" of these cells and transpose them into row. So desired output should looks like this one:

```
row    B            C            D                E
1      City_1       Street_1      StreetNo_1       State_1
4      City_2       Street_2      StreetNo_2       State_2
5      City_3       Street_3      StreetNo_3       State_3
9      City_4       Street_4      StreetNo_4       State_4
```

How could I do that in Excel VBA?

Comment: There are dozens of excellent examples on this site. Look at the **Related** section down the right-hand side or send the title of your question to a search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately, you could simply write a simple formula into the cells.

```
Sub a2bcde()
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1:E" & Int(ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row / 4)).Formula = "=OFFSET($A$1, (ROW(1:1)-1)*4+(COLUMN(A:A)-1), 0)"
End Sub
```

Transfer the formulas' values back to the cells or Copy, Paste Special, Values.

Comment: Thanks guys, I can start with approach of Jeeped. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This Function moves values from rows per four into four columns. This is exactly what you need. You will place this in developer tab, in visual basic

```
Sub MoveValues()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim lngLastRow As Long

    Set MyRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & "1")

    lngLastRow = Cells(65536, MyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1

    For i = 1 To lngLastRow Step 4

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 3, 1)).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        j = j + 1

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, could you explain me how it works. I'm new in excel vba and if I put this piece of code into excel vba Module and run this macro onto my data range, it starts debuging...

Comment: @MartinSmith - Saying something is giving an error without noting what the error message was or what line the debugger is pointing to is pointless.